# Containerized python script fails with StopIteration

Tags: python, mysql-connector, stopiteration

I am trying to write a python script which loads series of sql files in sequential manner.

It works without an issue on my local machine, but as soon as it's executed from within a container it fails.

Affected code

```
iterator = db_cursor.execute(sql_file.read(), multi=True)
            for res in iterator:
                logger.debug("executing query: [%s], affected %d rows", res, res.rowcount)
            iterator.close()
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 486, in _execute_iter

    result = next(query_iter)

StopIteration


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/migration.py", line 91, in <module>

    for res in iterator:

RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration
```

Any suggestion on how to rectify it?
Thanks.

**EDIT**
Looks like it's a bug within the library I was using. Noticed that I've been using `mysql-connector-python` on my local machine and `mysql-connector` on remote.

Solved now

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a bug within the library I was using. Noticed that I've been using mysql-connector-python on my local machine and mysql-connector on remote.